# Как обучить нейронную сеть/сети распознавать кривую?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Есть много данных, которые отражают кол-во лайков/репостов/комментов во времени. Классический пример органического прироста кол-ва лайков можно наблюдать на этой картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот это - пример плохого графика:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, вопрос - что почитать по нейронным сетям, чтобы натренировать их на распознавание хороших графиков?

Второй вопрос - можно ли обойтись без нейронных сетей?

Comment: Почему второй пример плохой? Ссылка на вас попала в специальный топ какого-то сайта и висит там. Линейный прирост количества лайков. Потом ссылка оттуда ушла.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, на втором скрине классический вариант накрутки лайков. Только сервисы по накрутке дают линейный рост.

Comment: Логично. Но зачем здесь нейронные сети? Вы руками не можете обнаружить прямые на графике?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov не всегда есть прямые, увы. часто встречается и "лесенка", и другие варианты. Вопрос в том - как распознать то, что на первом графике?

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Накрутка может быть и скачком на графике. Нужно собрать все возможные потенциальные события накрутки и при их возникновении считать, что это "плохой" график, а остальные - хорошие.

Comment: Вы подходите к задаче не так. У вас есть числовые данные, вы должны поискать в них закономерности. Вместо этого вы наносите данные на график, и пытаетесь на графике найти эти же закономерности, используя распознавание (то есть, усложняете себе задачу). Ищите нужные прямые и лесенки непосредственно в исходных данных.

Comment: Мы живём в таком мире, в котором люди считают, что мы уже прошли все возможные и невозможные точки сингулярности. 

На самом деле это, конечно, не так. Как минимум, точку компьютерной сингулярности мы ещё не прошли и в ближайшие *k* лет вряд ли пройдём. Я думаю, что *k > 10*. Т.е. в ближайшие k лет **НЕ ПОЯВИТСЯ БОЛЕЕ ИЛИ МЕНЕЕ универсального метода, который может по внешнему виду данных и текстовому описанию решить Вашу задачу**.

Comment: В связи с этим, по-прежнему, к каждой задаче нужно будет искать свой подход и предлагать своё, уникальное решение, пусть и слабо отличающееся от похожих задач в той или иной области.

Поэтому не нужно притягивать нейронные сети и т.п. методы за уши там, где они не нужны. И тем более там, где могут отработать более простые решения при примерно аналогичной вычислительной нагрузке и качестве.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, перед использованием нейронных сетей каким бы то ни было способом, попробуйте решить задачу лобовым методом: как Вы и говорите, определив, есть ли в данных прямая или нет. На самом деле, уже этот вопрос может озадачить. По крайней мере, если Вы решите эту подзадачу, наличие или отсутствие этого признака (есть ли участки на графике, представляющие собой прямые или их нет) можно будет использовать в более сложных алгоритмах: нейронных сетях, не нейронных сетях, решаюших лесах и не решаюших лесах и во всём, в чём Вы захотите. Скорее всего, такое свойство позволит существенно повысить качество решения Вашей задачи.

Сразу, конечно же, возникает вопрос, "как это задетектить эту прямую автоматически"? Сделать это несложно. Попробуйте считать производную на каждом участке. Т.е. у Вас задана функция {Y_i, t_i}. Посчитайте величину на всем заданном промежутке:

```
y_der = (y[i]-y[i-1])/(t[i]-t[i-1])
```

В таком случае, в каждой точке мы знаем угол наклона касательной (в нашем случае -- элементарного отрезочка). Теперь, если этот угол от шага к шагу варьируется слабо (т.е. график `y_der[i] == y_der[i+1]+eps`), то можно делать заключение, что перед нами линейная зависимость (достаточно подобрать удобный для Вас порог `eps`, которы можно взять единым для всех графиков (т.е. тот, который будет выдавать наилучшее решение в Вашей задаче).

Таким образом, можем сделать следующий признак:

```
is_linear = [y_der[i] - y_der[i+1] < eps]
```

Квадратными скобочками часто обозначают предикаты, т.е. если выражение истино, то предикат возвращает значение 1, в противном случае -- 0.

Теперь нам необходимо понять, где, действительно, у нас находится линейная зависимость, а где -- лишь локальное совпадение признака `is_linear`. Приведу пример:

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

В первом случае, вероятнее всего, мы имеем дело с локальным совпадением и линейной зависимости здесь нет. Во втором случае, скорее всего, мы имеем дело с одним участком линейной зависимости.

Будем определять наличие линейной зависимости по количеству подряд идущих единиц. Для того, чтобы это определять, можно также задаться порогом, который подбирается вручную (исходя из качества решения задачи).

В таком случае, для каждого нашего графика имеем новое свойство -- число отрезков, на которых присутствует линейная зависимость (можно добавить ещё и свойства их длинны или аналогичные им).

Уже визуализировав этот признак в координатах:

```
(Номер графика, Число линейных зависимостей)
```

скорее всего можно получить неплохое решение Вашей задачи.

Если же результат окажется неудовлетворительным или захочется лучшего. Сделайте аналогичных признаков и постройте Решаюший лес или логистическую регрессию. Но вот нейронные сети здесь Вам ни к чему.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721008/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-php-ml/723773#723773

Comment: Посмотрите, быть может это будет для Вас полезно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723336/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8/723440#723440

Comment: Ещё здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648151/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-c/648240#648240

Comment: И здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649761/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-png-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/651646#651646